# generate consistent machine unique ID

Tags: linux, shell-script, hardware, uuid, hashsum

Can we generate a unique id for each PC, something like uuuidgen, but it will never change unless there are hardware changes? I was thinking about  merging CPUID and MACADDR and hash them to generate a consistent ID, but I have no idea how to parse them using bash script, what I know is how can I get CPUID from

```
dmidecode -t 4 | grep ID
```

and

```
ifconfig | grep ether
```

then I need to combine those hex strings and hash them using sha1 or md5 to create fixed length hex string.
How can I parse that output?

Comment: What is exactly the problem you are trying to solve using this method?

Comment: I'm with Darkhogg. It's generally a bad idea to try to do these kinds of things this day-and-age.  Virtualization has made the practice of binding software to physical hardware kind of pointless.  There's usually a better answer if you closely examine your requirements (which is what Darkhogg is driving at).

Comment: i dont use this to bind a software to a machine, it is linux mining rig that need to identify itself to cloud control and monitoring service, instead of naming thousands of rig manually, i need to uniquely identify them using their hardware ID

Comment: @JoeRounceville - though I initially thought the same, I then remembered *SecureBoot*. As it turns out, *in this day and age* this kind of thing has become both more likely to happen and easier to do.

Comment: SecureBoot is one leaked Microsoft signing cert away from being pointless... and based on past experiences with signing certs from large companies, it's just a matter of time.

Comment: @user77710:  If that's the case, then do you really care about the hardware at all?  Why not just generate a UUID on the machine if one doesn't exist.  That's the point of a UUID -- they're universally unique (their odds of overlapping are astronomically improbable).

http://serverfault.com/questions/103359/how-to-create-a-uuid-in-bash

Comment: @JoeRounceville - I didn't mean that *SecureBoot* itself was the solution - though it does support self-signed certificates - but rather its *method*. But it uses an API offered by the system's *firmware* - and any UEFI system will have as many UUIDs as you could need already setup in the name of each firmware variable - see my answer. Also, you don't need any application - or `bash` - to generate you a UUID on any linux. `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about these two:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t 4 | grep ID | sed 's/.*ID://;s/ //g'
52060201FBFBEBBF
$ ifconfig | grep eth1 | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/://g'
0126c9da2c38
```

You can then combine and hash them with:

```
$ echo $(sudo dmidecode -t 4 | grep ID | sed 's/.*ID://;s/ //g') \
       $(ifconfig | grep eth1 | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/://g') | sha256sum 
59603d5e9957c23e7099c80bf137db19144cbb24efeeadfbd090f89a5f64041f  -
```

To remove the trailing dash, add one more pipe:

```
$ echo $(sudo dmidecode -t 4 | grep ID | sed 's/.*ID://;s/ //g') \
       $(ifconfig | grep eth1 | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/://g') | sha256sum |
  awk '{print $1}'
59603d5e9957c23e7099c80bf137db19144cbb24efeeadfbd090f89a5f64041f
```

---

As @mikeserv points out [in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144892/22222), the interface name [can change](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) between boots. This means that what is eth0 today might be eth1 tomorrow, so if you grep for `eth0` you might get a different MAC address on different boots. My system does not behave this way so I can't really test but possible solutions are:

1. Grep for `HWaddr` in the output of `ifconfig` but keep all of them, not just the one corresponding to a specific NIC. For example, on my system I have:

   ```
   $ ifconfig | grep HWaddr
   eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:a9:bd:2c:28  
   wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:16:19:4f:ac:g5
   ```

   By grabbing both MAC addresses and passing them through `sha256sum`, you should be able to get a unique and stable name, irrespective of which NIC is called what:

   ```
   $ echo $(sudo dmidecode -t 4 | grep ID | sed 's/.*ID://;s/ //g') \
        $(ifconfig | grep -oP 'HWaddr \K.*' | sed 's/://g') | sha256sum |
         awk '{print $1}'
   662f0036cba13c2ddcf11acebf087ebe1b5e4044603d534dab60d32813adc1a5
   ```

   Note that the hash is different from the ones above because I am passing both MAC addresses returned by `ifconfig` to `sha256sum`.
2. Create a hash based on the UUIDs of your hard drive(s) instead:

   ```
   $ blkid | grep -oP 'UUID="\K[^"]+' | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}'
   162296a587c45fbf807bb7e43bda08f84c56651737243eb4a1a32ae974d6d7f4
   ```

Comment: its nice, but how to get rid trailing dash '-' ?

Comment: @user77710 see updated answer.

Comment: I guess cpuid is worse... [wikipedia.org/wiki/cpuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cpuid)

Comment: @mikeserv ah, yes indeed, I see your point. Thanks, answer edited.

Comment: Generates same ID for all guest OS on same host.

Comment: Does not work with virtual instances, like a guest VirtualBox.

Answer (score 26):

Firstly, please note that the CPUID is definitely *not* a commonly accessible uniquely identifying marker for any system later than an Intel Pentium III. While hashing it with MAC addresses may lead to unique markers certainly, this is due only to the unique qualities of the MACs themselves and the CPUID in that case is nothing more than circumstantial. Moreover, the resulting hash is not likely to be any more unique than the motherboard's UUID, and that is far easier to retrieve and the process is a lot less prone to err. From [wikipedia.org/wiki/cpuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cpuid):

> **EAX=3**: Processor Serial Number
>
> See also: [Pentium III § Controversy about privacy issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_III#Controversy_about_privacy_issues)
>
> This returns the processor's serial number. The processor serial number was introduced on Intel Pentium III, but due to privacy concerns, this feature is no longer implemented on later models (PSN feature bit is always cleared). Transmeta's Efficeon and Crusoe processors also provide this feature. AMD CPUs however, do not implement this feature in any CPU models.

You can view a parsed cpuid yourself by doing `cat /proc/cpuinfo` or even just `lscpu`.

This gets you all of the MAC addresses for the network interfaces recognized by the linux kernel, I think:

```
ip a | sed '\|^ *link[^ ]* |!d;s|||;s| .*||'
```

It may be necessary to filter that list if it might include virtual nics with randomly generated MACs. You can do this with flags in the call to `ip` directly. See `ip a help` for information on how to do so.

Also note that this problem is not unique to `ip` and must also be dealt with if you use `ifconfig`, but that it can be more reliably handled with `ip` - which is part of the [`iproute2` network suite](http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html) and is actively maintained - than it can with `ifconfig` - which is a member of the [`net-tools` package](http://net-tools.sourceforge.net/) and last saw a Linux [release in 2001](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig#Release_status). Due to changing features in the kernel since its last release, `ifconfig` is known to [misreport some networking feature flags](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=102474) and its use should be avoided if at all possible.

Understand, though, that filtering with kernel interface names like `eth[0-9]` is not a reliable means of doing so, as these can change based on their order of paralleled detection by `udev` during the boot process. Please see [Predictable Network Names](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) for more on that.

Because `dmidecode` is not installed on my system I at first thought to hash a list of hard disk serials generated like:

```
lsblk -nro SERIAL
```

Do `lsblk --help` for some clues on refining that list - by disk type, say. Also consider `lspci` and/or `lsusb` maybe.

Combining them is easy:

```
{ ip a | sed ... ; lsblk ... ; } | #abbreviated... for brevity...
    tr -dc '[:alnum:]' | #deletes all chars not alphanumeric - including newlines
    sha256sum #gets your hash
```

As you've informed me you're keying user's resources on your end to their unique ids, and hard disks can not be relied upon to exist I thought to change my tack.

That considered, I looked into the filesystem again and found the `/sys/class/dmi/id` folder. I checked a few of the files:

```
cat ./board_serial ./product_serial

###OUTPUT###
To be filled by O.E.M.
To be filled by O.E.M.
```

However, this one seems to be pretty good, but I won't publish the output:

```
sudo cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
```

I expect that's where `dmidecode` gets much of its information anyway and in fact it [does look like it](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/System). According to [`man dmidecode`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode) you can also simplify your use of that tool a great deal by specifying the argument:

```
dmidecode -s system-uuid
```

More simple still, though, you can just read the file. Note that this particular file specifically identifies a motherboard. Here's an excerpt from the [2007 kernel patch](http://lwn.net/Articles/233385/) that originally implemented these exports to the `/sysfs` virtual filesystem:

```
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(bios_vendor,      0444, DMI_BIOS_VENDOR);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(bios_version,         0444, DMI_BIOS_VERSION);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(bios_date,        0444, DMI_BIOS_DATE);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(sys_vendor,       0444, DMI_SYS_VENDOR);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(product_name,         0444, DMI_PRODUCT_NAME);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(product_version,   0444, DMI_PRODUCT_VERSION);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(product_serial,    0400, DMI_PRODUCT_SERIAL);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(product_uuid,         0400, DMI_PRODUCT_UUID);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(board_vendor,         0444, DMI_BOARD_VENDOR);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(board_name,       0444, DMI_BOARD_NAME);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(board_version,     0444, DMI_BOARD_VERSION);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(board_serial,         0400, DMI_BOARD_SERIAL);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(board_asset_tag,   0444, DMI_BOARD_ASSET_TAG);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(chassis_vendor,    0444, DMI_CHASSIS_VENDOR);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(chassis_type,         0444, DMI_CHASSIS_TYPE);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(chassis_version,   0444, DMI_CHASSIS_VERSION);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(chassis_serial,    0400, DMI_CHASSIS_SERIAL);
+DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(chassis_asset_tag, 0444, DMI_CHASSIS_ASSET_TAG);
```

You may be able to use that data alone to identify the system - if the motherboard is enough. But you can combine this information with the system's MACs in the same way I demonstrated you might do with hard disks:

```
sudo sh <<\CMD | tr -dc '[:alnum:]' | sha256sum
        ip a | sed '\|^ *link[^ ]* |!d;s|||;s| .*||'
        cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid 
CMD
```

The Linux kernel can also generate UUIDs for you:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid #new random uuid each time file is read
```

Or:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id #randomly generated per boot
```

Granted, it's randomly generated and you will have to rethink ID assignment, but it's about as easy as it gets to *get* at least. And it should be pretty solid if you can find a means to key it.

Last, on UEFI systems this becomes far easier to do - as every EFI firmware environment variable includes its own UUID. The environment variable `{Platform,}LangCodes-${UUID}` should be present on every UEFI system, should persist reboots and even *most* firmware upgrades and modifications, and any Linux system with the `efivarfs` module loaded can list either or both names as simply as:

```
printf '%s\n' /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/*LangCodes-*
```

The older form - `LangCodes-${UUID}` is apparently [now deprecated](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2010/01/accessing-uefi-global-variables-from-user-space-in-fedora-12.html), and on newer systems should be `PlatformLangCodes-${UUID}` but, according to spec, one or the other should be present in every UEFI system. With little effort, you can define your own reboot persistent variables, and maybe make more use of the kernel's UUID generator in that way. If interested, look into [efitools](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/jejb/efitools.git).

Comment: it doesn't even have harddisk or any disk running, its mining rig, if you dont know what it is see this http://diit.cz/sites/default/files/images/3988/litecoin_rig_s_radeony_02.jpg virtual machine can't run 6 GPU on single motherboard

Comment: anyway it should never use any random number as it beat the purpose of consistenly naming the machine, as they boot up the ID shouldn't change

Comment: @user77710 - Dang, man, that thing is cool. Is that one machine? Probably you're right, but it might be possible with some combo of XDMX and Chromium - some distributed graphics stuff. Anyway, it wouldn't matter - I had it backwards. Who would want to beat themselves out of their money? I was thinking some software licensing thing or something - you're doing bank accounts.

Comment: Them's some nifty tricks you got there, +1.

Comment: @terdon - the compliment is much appreciated, but, for the most part, they're not tricks. `ip2` is specifically designed to be parsed, and it may be that I'm not doing it well enough - I suspect the same thing can be done almost without `grep/sed`. Probably the same could be done as easily with `udevadm`. And each EFI environment variable name is designed to be uniquely identified for exactly these sorts of situations.

Comment: Ohhh... no hard drive.  Hmmm... that makes things interesting I guess.  Is there _any_ form of static storage on these things?

Comment: @JoeRounceville - dunno. There is almost definitely firmware - though I have not had any feedback about whether it is UEFI or not. Still, the kernel *should* report the motherboard's UUID - which is pretty static I guess. Also, there are apparently nics, so maybe an oprom flash could be done? Then again the very act of doing so invalidates the concept of unique MACs - even if you don't rewrite the MAC you've proved you *can*.

Answer (score 25):

Many modern distributions ship a file `/etc/machine-id` containing a most probably unique hexadecimal 32-character string. It originates from systemd, where [a manpage has more information](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html), and may be appropriate for your purpose.

Comment: +1, @XZS, you could add the relevant information from the URL here as well.

Comment: This is good, and I found similar information and almost used it... but I was already committed to a different route. Still, it should be noted that this is `dbus` specific, I think, and changes if an operating system is wiped/reinstalled.

Comment: This is pretty darn awesome.

Answer (score 9):

On a lot of Linux machines, the file `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` contains a unique id for each Linux distribution and can be accessed by a call to `dbus_get_local_machine_id()`. This is probably the same as the `/etc/machine-id` mentioned above. It works on virtual Linux installations too. I've checked it on current Ubuntu, SuSE and CentOS distributions.

Comment: In Fedora 19 + 20 that file does not exist. It's here: `/etc/machine-id`.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. My point was that if you don't find it one place, look in the other. Or write your own program using the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the machine ID to change when the hardware changes? Is the machine ID being used to protect something? The best way I believe to have a "consistent" machine ID is by storing a random string somewhere on the system and that way if any of the hardware changes, then the machine ID won't change either. This is also good for virtualized systems where hardware access is restricted and the MAC ID is 00:00:00:00

Try something like this sh script to create and get the ID:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE="/etc/machine-id"

if [ ! -f $FILE ]; then
    cat /dev/urandom|tr -dc A-Z0-9|head -c32 > $FILE;
fi

cat $FILE;
```

Comment: Since your `/dev/urandom` indicates Linux anyway, you can just do `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid >$FILE` which randomly generates a properly formatted UUID on every read. Still, any disk-implemented persistence is subject to deletion, and, provided that is acceptable, and provided `dbus` is installed, you should probably do as @XZS has suggested instead.

Comment: @mikeserv Since /etc/machine-id is used by systemd, I think you should not change the format of the uuid.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers give a number of ways of extracting ids from hardware. You could decide to use one piece of hardware as the identifier or many. This is problematic if you need to swap or replace pieces of hardware arbitrarily.

Some people might instead store id a generated id on their harddrive (or use the UUID) but harddrides can be clone.

TPM modules and secure boot might provide a means of binding motherboard and other hardware with an install onto a harddrive.

It's always a bit easier in these cases if you give more information about what you want to accomplish.