# What command always generates the same UUID through /proc/sys/kernel

Tags: proc, uuid

Running the following command generates different random output on each execution (which is expected, considering that `random` is in the path):

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid`

Is there any way to modify the path so that it results in a static (not random) UUID on each call (return the same thing on each request/execution instead of being random)?

Comment: This doesn't make sense much. A `uuid (Universal Unique IDentifier)` is meant to be unique among system's generated uuid's as well as global known uuid's. If you want to refer to the same uuid you generate, just use  `mystaticuuid=$(uuidgen)` and then call it using `echo "$mystaticuuid"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having recently needed to build some licensing functionality into an application (the problem I was trying to solve when first posting this question), I found that it's possible to obtain a static UUID from one of the following files:

```
/etc/machine-id  # preferred
/var/lib/dbus/machine-id  # Usually a symlink to /etc/machine-id
/var/db/dbus/machine-id  # usually a symlink/alternative to /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid  # Will vary on each invocation, so save output to another file 
  # (as per roaima's answer).
```

In the above list of files, they're listed from most preferred to least preferred.

Comment: If `machine_id` is not available, another fallback for obtaining a static, per-machine ID would be to hash `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub`

Comment: Thank you. That could work too. I'm not sure why you suggest hashing it, since it is my understanding is that the contents of that file is already a hash of a prime number.

Comment: Yes, ultimately it contains a hash, but it also has structure around it.  It's a text file, and even if you just look at the base64-encoded part of it, you'll see it always begins with "AAAA".  So you could base64 decode it, and then know enough about the binary structure to extract just the hash part.  Or you could just hash the whole file, which is easier.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm all for taking the easier approach if there is one.

Answer (score 6):

You asked

> Is there any way to modify the path so that it results in a static (not random) UUID on each call

And the answer to this is "yes, definitely".

If you prepare the environment like this:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid >/tmp/uuid
```

You can modify the path to get a static UUID on each call, like this

```
cat /tmp/uuid
```

Comment: Well, that's obvious, I suppose. (I blame lack of sleep for not thinking that through.)

Comment: @Agi what are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: What I actually want to do is create a unique ID for a machine running GNU/Linux, thinking that running a slight adaptation of `/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` would be the way to go. On Windows, I can run `wmic DISKDRIVE get SerialNumber` and query the registry for the value of `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid` to get values I can work with. I was wondering if I could achieve something similar with GNU/Linux (other than getting the HWAddrs of all NICs in the machine and hashing them, as I have seen suggested). However, I'll ask a separate question for that.

Comment: I have some existing Java software that uses a Windows-specific DLL to retrieve hardware information and generate a hashed UID for the machine on which it runs (implementation details of which are known to me). I'm trying to port it to GNU/Linux and the licensing is what prevents me from porting it. (The output doesn't *have* to be the same on both platforms, but it would be advantageous if it is.)

Comment: @AgiHammerthief take a look at [generate consistent machine unique ID](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144812/generate-consistent-machine-unique-id)

Comment: Have you considered `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id` ?